# calculus and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we suppose $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n =0,$ I have to examine if $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  } n^{\frac {1}{1+a_n}}$ converges or diverges.

I used the monotone convergence theorem to show that the series diverges. If we suppose: $a_n=\dfrac {1}{n},$ then $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n= \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac {1}{n}=0. $$ Let the sequence of functions $f$ on $\mathbb{N}$ be defined by $$f_n (k)= k^{\frac{1}{1+\frac {1}{n}}}.$$ We note that these functions are positive, and that for each $k$, as a sequence in $n, f_n (k)$ is increasing. The sum over $k$ is an integral and it's the integral over $\mathbb{N}$ with respect to counting measure. In particular, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem (from the Lebesgue theory) allows to interchange limit and integral:

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  } k^{\frac {1}{1+\frac {1}{n}}} = \sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  } \lim_{n\to+\infty} k^{\frac {1}{1+\frac {1}{n}}}= \sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  } \frac{1}{k}= +\infty$$

and then $$ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  } k^{\frac {1}{1+\frac {1}{n}}} $$ diverges. By the same argument, $$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  } k^{\frac {1}{1+a_n}}$$  diverges.

Comment: OK, so you have the result for $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. What goes wrong in your proof if you take a generic $a_n$?

Comment: I don't know, I am wondering if I am wrong for any $$a_n$$. My professor told me that there is a more general case, but I don't know what he means

Comment: George: single variables, or sequences like $a_n$, do not require two dollar-signs in mathjax.  A single dollar-sign on each end is most appropriate is such context.

Comment: It is maybe an English expression, that I cannot understand

Comment: @George Try it! Work through the proof without that assumption. Does anything go wrong? 

Before you get there, though, you might want to stare at your claim that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}k^{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=\dfrac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is not rather to examine the convergence of $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  } n^{-\frac {1}{1+a_n}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Surely divergent. We have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {1\over 1+a_n}=1$$ therefore for large enough $n$ we have $${1\over 1+a_n}>{1\over 2}$$by substitution we obtain$$n^{{1\over 1+a_n}}>n^{1\over 2}=\sqrt n$$from which we can conclude that the series diverge since $\sum \sqrt n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is absolutely diverging because $n^x$ is equal or greater than $1$ for $n \geq 1$ and $x \geq 0$.